# is it possible to fetch data from a remote api while admin is writing a new post?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, rest-api, api

Editor picture:

[image]

I wonder if it is possible to fetch data from a remote api while user is typing a new post inside the editor. That data should be shown anywhere in the screen (I mean, inside the editor). Is that possible? If so, how? Thank you very much in advance

Data to be fetch: video title 1, link to video title 1, code to embed video1 into post. video title2, link to video title2, code to embed video 2 into post.

This development will be installed on many machines. I think it should be a plugin. I am thinking about making a Chrome extension as well

Please take into account that data should be fetched while user is typing a new post and that data should be shown on a sidebar (while user is typing). The idea is that the user types some characters, data is fetched **based on** those characters. Data received is code to **embed** a video inside post

Comment: Without knowing what this data is or what it's doing  it's difficult to advise where it should be shown, or how to trigger the request, but yes it's possible to make requests in javascript. If you can expand a  little on what you're actually doing perhaps an answer can be written?

Comment: @TomJNowell thank you very much for your answer, I have just edited my question. How would you do it?

Comment: hi @pablofiumara yes it's possible, you need to do ajax call depending upon your algorithm and you can add a meta box on edit post page with the fields and get the data to the relevant fields.

Comment: @Akshat thank you. do you have any open source code example?

Comment: I don't have one now, but you can research about how to make the scripts work at the edit post page and proceed with writing the ajax depending upon your algorithm.

Comment: I decided to make a Chrome web extension that works for Wordpress pages